# ANTLR4 Correctly continuing to parse sections after error

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to write some tooling (validation/possibly autocomplete) for a SQL-esk query language.  However, parser is tokenizing invalid/incomplete inputs in a way that is making it more difficult to work with.

I've reduce my scenario to its simplest reproducible form.  Here is my minimized grammar:

```
grammar SOQL;

WHITE_SPACE : ( ' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n' ) -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

FROM    : 'FROM' ;
SELECT  : 'SELECT' ;

/********** SYMBOLS **********/


COMMA       : ',' ;

ID: ( 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | '$') ( 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | '$' | '0'..'9' )* ;

soql_query:    select_clause from_clause;
select_clause: SELECT field ( COMMA field )*;
from_clause:   FROM table;

field : ID;
table : ID;
```

When I run the following code (using [antlr4ts](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts), but it should be similar to any other port):

```
const input = 'SELECT ID, Name, Website, Contact, FROM Account'; //invalid trailing ,
let inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(input);
let lexer = new SOQLLexer(inputStream);
let tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
let parser = new SOQLParser(tokenStream);

let qry = parser.soql_query();
let select = qry.select_clause();
console.log('FIELDS: ', select.field().map(field => field.text));
console.log('FROM: ', qry.from_clause().text);
```

**Console Log**

```
line 1:35 extraneous input 'FROM' expecting ID
line 1:47 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting 'FROM'
FIELDS: Array(5) ["ID", "Name", "Website", "Contact", "FROMAccount"]
FROM:
```

I get errors (which is expected), but I was hoping it would still be able to correctly pick out the `FROM` clause.

It was my understanding since `FROM` is a identifier, it's not a valid field in the `select_clause` (maybe I'm just misunderstanding)?

Is there some way to setup the grammar or parser so that it will continue on to properly identify the `FROM` clause in this scenario (and other common WIP query states).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It was my understanding since FROM is a identifier, it's not a valid
>   field in the select_clause (maybe I'm just misunderstanding)?

All the parser sees is a discrete stream of typed tokens coming from the lexer. The parser has no intrinsic way to tell if a token is intended to be an identifier, or for that matter, have any particular semantic nature.

In designing a fault-tolerant grammar, plan the parser to be fairly permissive to syntax errors and expect to use several tree-walkers to progressively identify and where possible resolve the syntax and semantic ambiguities.

Two ANTLR features particularly useful to this end include:

1) implement a lexer TokenFactory and custom token, typically extending CommonToken.  The custom token provides a convenient space for flags and logic for identifying the correct syntactic/semantic use and expected context for a particular token instance.

2) implement a parser error strategy, extending or expanding on the [DefaultErrorStrategy](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.java). The error strategy will allow modest modifications to the parser operation on the token stream when an attempted match results in a recognition error. If the error cannot be fully resolved and appropriately fixed upon examining the surrounding (custom) tokens, at least those same custom tokens can be suitably annotated to ease problem resolution during the subsequent tree-walks.

Comment: sounds like I have some more studying to do. Any suggestions on where to start?  I assume these topics are covered in "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" book?

Comment: There is also Parr's `Language Implementation Patterns`, but neither it nor TDAR address the issue in detail. Beyond that, it requires a bit of trial and error to figure out where/how to defend against any particular bit of garbage input.  Very application dependent.